# Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing one Flash Light application in Silverlight for windows phone 8. Currently 
I am deeply stuck in one issue for the use of "Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended" assembly. Flash Light Application for Windows phone 7 is already live in Windows Phone Marketplace and it is working very fine for Windows Phone 7 but it is not working for Windows Phone 8 because of  "Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended" dll.

After converting WP7 app into wp8 and run then I got this type of error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended,Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find file specific."

According to following link  for Windows Phone-specific features:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx

> If you were using reflection to access the API in this assembly, because they were not publicly exposed, your app may fail on a Windows Phone 8 device. Remove the calls to this assembly and use the publicly exposed media API.

I an not understanding how to use  publicly exposed media API. I used Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended using reflaction in Windows Phone 7.  Is there any direct method for accessing Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended in Windows Phone 8 or other way to solve this?

Thanks.

==========================================================================
Edited Question:

Hi,

As per the thread, we used "VideoTorchMode" enumeration to make flashlight ON. As per that, I used AudioVideoCaptureDevice class using Windows.Phone.Media.Capture namespace with following code:

```
    var objDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolution(CameraSensorLocation.Back).First());
    objDevice .SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);
```

I want to keep the flash light on but without capturing video. So, i have not initialized video capture code. The issue is, i don’t have WP8 yet and in simulator i am not able to test this.

Can any one confirm that once i put this code, my app will work as Flashlight-X where light will be on without blinking and also it will not get crashed in WP8.

Thanks

Comment: `Is there any direct method for accessing Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended in Windows Phone 8` The point is, that DLL has been removed in WP8, so you can't use it anymore. There's WP8-compatible flashlight apps on the marketplace, so there must be an equivalent API somewhere. Time to dig in the MSDN documentation ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended is a private API in WP7 that wasn't meant to be used by 3rd party developers. That API doesn't exist or works on WP8.

For WP8 flashlight use the AudioVideoCaptureDevice known property of VideoTorchMode=On. Also, make sure to handle failures like exceptions or devices that don't have a Camera Torch by showing a white screen.

Here's a code sample that turns on the camera flash on my Lumia 820 and Lumia 920:

```cs
var sensorLocation = CameraSensorLocation.Back;

try
{
    // get the AudioViceoCaptureDevice
    var avDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensorLocation,
        AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensorLocation).First());

    // turn flashlight on
    var supportedCameraModes = AudioVideoCaptureDevice
        .GetSupportedPropertyValues(sensorLocation, KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode);
    if (supportedCameraModes.ToList().Contains((UInt32)VideoTorchMode.On))
    {
        avDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);

        // set flash power to maxinum
        avDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchPower,
            AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyRange(sensorLocation, KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchPower).Max);
    }
    else
    {
        ShowWhiteScreenInsteadOfCameraTorch();
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Flashlight isn't supported on this device, instead show a White Screen as the flash light
    ShowWhiteScreenInsteadOfCameraTorch();
}
```

Make sure to add the required capabilities and requirements to your WP8 app when using the camera torch (ISV_Camera, Microphone, and ID_REQ_BACK_Camera).

Comment: Hi, Justin.. works like a charm.. Thanks a lot .. u r a true savior. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry for late comment. Your solution worked great and app stopped crashing. However, in WP8, the light start and stops in a second. That's it. I actually wanted to have a light which is on continuously till user press the button. Means which user click on, light is on without blink and when user click off, light will be off. Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

What about getting this assembly from somewhere and adding it to your XAP directly (try asking on XDA developers)? This might work, if it's signed and not requiring any special capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new API to "record" a video, then using the [VideoTorchMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.videotorchmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) enumeration might do just want you want to create a "flashlight" effect.

Comment: Hi.. just edited my question based on your answer Claus. Thanks for your help and information.