# How do you turn on the camera flash without taking pictures?

Tags: windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wp8 - Reflection API issue - Please check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check)

I know you can [control the camera flash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) but that only seems to actually turn on the flash when you take a picture or record video. I also found one other way to turn it on by focusing the camera.

Is there a way to turn the LED flash on without either of these battery intensive hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible to do that on WP8 using public APIs, please see my answer @ [Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check/13473773#13473773)

There's also a way to do that for WP7, see @ http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started