# Close VideoTorch after use

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a simple Flash Light application for WP8, and I am using the great example code by JustinAngel in this question: [Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check/13473773#13473773)

My question is; How do I close the camera flash? I Have been trying with setting the VideoTorchMode.Off property, but when I try to initiate the camera again using the code below, it just throws me the following error: `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

```
// get the AudioViceoCaptureDevice
var avDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensorLocation,
   AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensorLocation).First());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache the avDevice for later use. Don't initialize it multiple times and make sure to dispose of it once you're done with it.

Comment: Thank you so much @JustinAngel! If I had just quit working before midnight, I might have come up with that eventually, hehe. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. :-)