# WP8 - Flashlight without blink - how to achieve?

Tags: windows-phone-8

With reference to thread [Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check), I am facing the issue related to flash light. To revise, I would like to achieve the same
as http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/flashlight-x/2638b778-5eab-45f1-a511-a08e1dbde751 where the flash light get turned on and kept on without blink.

---

As per the above thread, I have been fine but in WP8 and using VideoTorchMode to make light on but; the flash light gets started and stops in a second. I want to have a light which is on continuously till user presses the button. Means which user click on, light is on without blink and when user click off, light will be off. 
Is there any property that I am missing or am I using totally wrong method to achieve like flashlight-x? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just the AudioVideoCaptureDevice turning itself off.

Have you tried caching the avDevice variable outside the scope of that method for later use? Just make sure that the instance doesn't go out of scope while you need it.

Comment: Not getting the whole idea. Bit confused. I have put the code you have given last time which was fine but with the above issue of blink. If possible, can you please send the snippet of the code?

Comment: Keep the avDevice variable alive in a private field and don't let it go out of scope. C# fields intro @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx