# Windows Phone 8 (HTC 8X) Flashlight does not turn on(Without using camera)

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection, windows-phone-8, flashlight

As a newbie programmer I am going to ask a silly question. I want to turn on the flashlight of windows phone 8 without blinking (continous like other flashlight apps). Now I tried to use the sample example of
[Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check/13473773#13473773)

but it did not work. I created a button called 'flash' and paste the code. It compiled fine, but my device HTC 8X does not turn on the flashlight even for a second. What I should do ?

The library & code I used :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Flashlight_V_0._1.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Media;
using Windows.Phone.Media.Capture; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;                     

namespace Flashlight_V_0._1
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sensorLocation = CameraSensorLocation.Back;

            try
            {
                // get the AudioViceoCaptureDevice
                var avDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensorLocation,
                    AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensorLocation).First());

                // turn flashlight on
                var supportedCameraModes = AudioVideoCaptureDevice
                    .GetSupportedPropertyValues(sensorLocation, KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode);
                if (supportedCameraModes.ToList().Contains((UInt32)VideoTorchMode.On))
                {
                    avDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);

                    // set flash power to maxinum
                    avDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchPower,
                        AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyRange(sensorLocation, KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchPower).Max);
                }
                else
                {
                    //ShowWhiteScreenInsteadOfCameraTorch();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Flashlight isn't supported on this device, instead show a White Screen as the flash light
                //ShowWhiteScreenInsteadOfCameraTorch();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
        try
        {

            var _device = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).First());

            _device.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you get any exception in your catch blocks that might cause your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was expecting the flashlight will turn on, may be not continuous but may be a blink. I got a unhandled exception only when I try to open the flashlight. Sorry, I am totally new and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply, got it ago but could not post.Sorry for that.
WP7/WP7.5 gives default to access all the sensors. But in WP8, you have to manually enable the sensors capability.

1. Go to the solution explorer.
2. Select the project.
3. Select Properties -> WMAppManifest.xml
4. Double Click on 'WMAppManifest.xml'
5. Select 'Capabilities'
6. Enable proper capability for app

To resolve my problem I had to enable two capabilities.

1. ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA
2. ID_CAP_MICROPHONE

Thank YOU