# Access ambient light sensor readings and display backlight level in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sensors

I am trying to design an application that makes use of the ambient lighting conditions and the screen's brightness levels to make some calculations. I need to make two versions of this app, one for Windows Phone 8, and one for Windows 8 for tablets and PCs. I have searched high and low but I can only find Light Sensor api's for Windows 8. I have not been able to find any API's to access the ambient light sensor on a Windows Phone 8 device and I have not seen anywhere that allows me to determine the screen's brightness level (for either PC or phone). Would anyone know how to access the ambient light sensor (als) readings and the brightness level of the display (screen) in Windows Phone 8? I would also like to access the display's brightness level for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others searching an answer to this question.

In Windows Phone 8 (until now, meaning GDR 3) - there is no API for accessing the ambient light sensor. All refferences pointing to `Windows.Devices.Sensors.LightSensor` are related to Windows 8, not Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 2):

Device sensors values are available from the Windows.Devices.Sensors namespace

More specifically, the LightSensor class for the ambient light sensor.

```
var lightSensor = Windows.Devices.Sensors.LightSensor;
```

The backlight is accessible using setting the properties KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode / VideoTorchPower on AudioVideoCaptureDevice

There's a code sample [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check/13473773#13473773) that will probably do what you are looking for

Don't forget to add the required capabilities to the manifest.

Comment: Hello Patrick. Thank you so much for your help. I tried the code in the example and I was indeed able to turn on the light to the rear of the phone. I have edited my question to give a little bit more insight into what I am trying to accomplish. Sadly, I have searched the light sensors in the windows phone and it says that they do not exist in this namespace. When I said backlight, I meant the level of the screen's brightness. Do you any idea where I should start? Maybe some more private API's might have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with Windows Phone 8.1

For more information please check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor