# Control LED on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I control the LED on Windows Phone, using C#.
Is it possible to control the intensity (dim it) or it fixed (on/off)?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: [Reflection failure when attempting to access Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454422/wp8-reflection-api-issue-please-check/13473773#13473773)

In the code you can see how to set it on max using setProperty and KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchPower. If you wish to set it to a specific power value, use the GetSupportedPropertyRange method to get the device specific range for the power property.